# Error while injecting service dependency to controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I have created one service and I want to inject dependency to controller, but it showing some error like

`angular.js:12477 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ResultProvider <- Result <- ToolbarController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=ResultProvider%20%3C-%20Result%20%3C-%20ToolbarController
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4289:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4437:39)
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4294:45
    at getService (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4437:39)
    at invoke (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4469:13)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4486:27)
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9151:28
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:4018:28
    at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8789:9) <md-toolbar id="toolbar" class="md-menu-toolbar md-whiteframe-1dp md-background-bg ng-scope" ui-view="toolbar">`

### api.service.js

```
api.sharedResult = $resource(api.dataUrl + 'sharedResult/sharedResult.json', null, {
  get: {method: 'get'}
});
```

In module I have written like

### toolbar.module.js

```
(function ()
{
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.toolbar', [])
    .config(config);

/** @ngInject */
function config($stateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider)
{
    $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('app/toolbar');


    $stateProvider.state('app.toolbar', {
        url    : '/sharedwishlistdetails',
        views  : {
            'content@app': {
                templateUrl: 'app/toolbar/sharedwishlistdetails.html',
                controller : 'ToolbarController as vm'
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            Result: function (apiResolver)
            {
                return apiResolver.resolve('sharedResult@get');
            }
        }

    });   
}
})();
```

In controller I have injected like below

### toolbar.controller.js

```
(function ()
{
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.toolbar')
    .controller('ToolbarController', ToolbarController);


function ToolbarController(Result, $rootScope, $mdSidenav, msNavFoldService, $translate, $mdToast, $location, $localStorage, $http,  $scope)
{
    var vm = this;
    vm.sharedResult = Sharedresult.sharedResult;
}
})();
```

### sharedwithlistdetails.html

```
<div id="sharedwishlistdetails" class="page-layout simple tabbed">
  <!-- HEADER -->
  <div class="header md-accent-bg" layout="row" layout-align="start center">
    <div class="title">
      <span class="md-display-1 font-weight-300">Shared Wishlist Details</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- / HEADER -->

  <md-content>
    <div class="head">
      <h2>Shared Wishlist Details</h2>
    </div>
    <hr/ style="width:1000px">
  </md-content>

  <md-content layout-padding>
    <div ng-repeat="data in vm.rslt">
      <h2>{{data.wName}}</h2>
    </div>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

Comment: what are the other dependencies?

Comment: Which exactly provider is unknown, please post whole Error

Comment: `Result` dependency is giving error. I have updated my question.

Comment: post the code of result provide/sevier/factory

Comment: I have created one json file `sharedResult.json`. Some data stored in that file. To get that result to controller I have created like this `api.sharedResult = $resource(api.dataUrl + 'sharedResult/sharedResult.json', null, {
  get: {method: 'get'}
});` and called in module. I have done same like this another but it was working perfectly but it gives error like this.

Comment: Could you share the code for the `sharedwishlistdetails.html` template?

Comment: `<div id="sharedwishlistdetails" class="page-layout simple tabbed">
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div class="header md-accent-bg" layout="row" layout-align="start center">
   <div class="title">
   <span class="md-display-1 font-weight-300">Shared Wishlist Details</span>
         </div>
    </div>
    <!-- / HEADER -->
 
 <md-content>
  <div class="head">
   <h2>Shared Wishlist Details</h2>
  </div>
  <hr/ style="width:1000px">
 </md-content>

 <md-content layout-padding>
  
   <div ng-repeat="data in vm.rslt">
     <h2>{{data.wName}}</h2>
   </div>
 </md-content>    
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

This line from the error message:

> at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8789:9)

```
<md-toolbar id="toolbar" ... ui-view="toolbar">
```

indicates the `ui-view` has been set with a specified state.

You'll need to change it to:

```
<md-toolbar ... ui-view>
```

Comment: If I change like that toolbar is not appearing.